# How to check and validate Iranian National Code (Melli Code) in Flutter?

Tags: validation, flutter, methods, dart

How to validate Iranian 10 digits national code in Flutter (Dart)?

It has a specific pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following method is written in Dart based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603570/how-to-validate-iranian-melli-code-national-code-or-code-melli-in-android/44603571#44603571) android code and is tested to validate Iranian National Code (Melli-Code) in Flutter:

```
 bool validateNationalCode(String nc) {
    if (nc.trim() == '') {
      return false;
    } else if (nc.length != 10) {
      return false;
    } else {
      int sum = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        sum += int.parse(nc[i]) * (10 - i);
      }

      int lastDigit;
      int divideRemaining = sum % 11;

      if (divideRemaining < 2) {
        lastDigit = divideRemaining;
      } else {
        lastDigit = 11 - (divideRemaining);
      }

      if (int.parse(nc[9]) == lastDigit) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```