# How to validate National Identity (Shenaseh Meli) of Iranian legal people

Tags: java, android, validation

I need a method to validate the National Identity of Iranian legal people.

I have National Code validation method of Iranian natural people [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44603571/6444297), but now I need National ID validation of Iranian legal people or companies

Comment: How do they differ? can you provide an example?

Comment: These are two different unique codes that Iran government give to natural and legal persons. National ID is granted to legal persons and National Code is for natural persons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a function to do so:

```
private boolean validateNationalOrgId(String nationalNo) {
    int[] MULT = {29, 27, 23, 19, 17, 29, 27, 23, 19, 17};
    int length = nationalNo.length();
    if (StringUtils.isNumeric(nationalNo) && length == 11) {
        char[] chars = nationalNo.toCharArray();
        int checkDigit = Character.getNumericValue(chars[length - 1]);
        int delta = 0;
        int tensPlusTwo = Character.getNumericValue(chars[length - 2]) + 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
            delta += ((Character.getNumericValue(chars[i]) + tensPlusTwo) * MULT[i]);
        }
        int remain = delta % 11;
        remain = remain == 10 ? 0 : remain;
        return remain == checkDigit;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Saleh. Do you have Iran Economic Code validation, too?

Comment: @AlirezaNoorali I am not aware of any validation formula for economic code (and doubt if exists)